# VS2019 Live Share - is it possible to share console as well?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-liveshare

I worked on a Console Application with a friend today. Is it possible to share the default console during a Live Share session? What I mean is that we had to compile and run our program manually through the default Windows Terminal to see output(which wasn't the best idea, there was a ton of empty lines displayed every time we would input anything), and debugging was impossible because we just couldn't see the console (only the host could).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/vs#share-a-terminal), it's possible to share the terminal in both VS Code and Visual Studio, but I don't think there's a way to share the console that comes up when you debug a console app. The solution I see is simply sharing a terminal, running your app in it manually and if you want debugging, you can try attaching the VS debugger to the console app's process after you start it manually by following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019).